# Control from WPFToolkit doesn't exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I added to references WPFToolkit.dll and I added do my .xaml file following line:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WpfToolkit"
```

and before following line:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
```

In both cases in line

```
<toolkit:NumericUpDown Value="10" Increment="1" Maximum="10" Minimum="0" />
```

I have error:

> Error 1   The tag 'NumericUpDown' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit'. Line 20 Position 18.   C:\Users\Diament\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyBasicFlyffKeystroke\MyBasicFlyffKeystroke\Window.xaml  20  18  MyBasicFlyffKeystroke

Where is the problem? :(

Comment: It looks like `NumericUpDown` is obsolete. From: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown. "[OBSOLETE] - Please use one of the new DecimalUpDown, DoubleUpDown, or IntegerUpDown controls"

Comment: With IntegerUpDown I have same error

Comment: Did you ever get this issue figured out?

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem.

If I *skipped* the unblock step and simply unzipped, the xaml preview window would not load and VS would keep giving me the 'IntegerUpDown component does not exist in the namespace http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit' error, even though auto-complete would happily list all the components in that namespace.

However if I **unblock** the zip file first, then extract, then reference the dll in VS, it all works correctly.

**TL;DR:** follow the [installation instructions](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation) *exactly*, particularly ***unblocking*** the zip file first.

Answer (score 5):

NumericUpDown is not part of the [basic WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) but part of the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Use the IntegerUpDown (or any of the [provided derived classes](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown-derived%20controls&referringTitle=Documentation)) and be sure to use the appropriate DLL in your application. Here is an example using the IntegerUpDown when the Extended WPF Toolkit DLL (*Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Dll*) is referenced by your project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
      <toolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="10" Increment="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

Comment: did you by any chance rename the dll? it should be WPFToolkit.Extended.dll

Comment: I didn't rename it. I just wrote my own control. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've followed @Andrew suggestion (download, unblock, extract, add), but still had the same issue.

Instead, the install through the NUGET (follow the instructions on their page [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation)) made it work without the need to do the manual steps.

Go go nuget ...

Answer (score 2):

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation

**Installation and Usage Instructions**

Please note: The Extended WPF Toolkit is dependent on .NET Framework 4.0. You must install .NET Framework 4.0 in order to use any features in the Toolkit.

**Instructions for using the Extended WPF Toolkit binaries:**

```
1.Install .NET Framework 4.0. 
2.Download the ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries 
3.Unblock the ZIP file. 1.Right-click ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip -> Properties -> Unblock 

4.Unzip the ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip 
5.Reference the binaries in your project: 
    1.Reference WPFToolkit.Extended.dll in your project (Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.dll for the datagrid control) 
    2.Add a using statement ("using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;" for most of the controls, "using Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;" for the datagrid control) to the top of .cs files 
    3.Add a new xmlns (xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" for most of the controls, xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" for the datagrid control) to the top of XAML files 
    4.Remember to use the namespace prefix (in the above example, <xctk: ...> or <xcdg: ...>) in the body of your XAML
```

**Installation using NuGet**

```
1.Install NuGet (can be downloaded for  this link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c). 
2.Open your Visual Studio. 
3.Open your solution/project. 
4.Open Tools menu, select Library Package Manager and select  Package Manager Console 
5.Run the following command Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit 
    1.Add a using statement ("using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;" for most of the controls, "using Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;" for the datagrid control) to the top of .cs files

    2.Add a new xmlns (xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" for most of the controls, xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" for the datagrid control) to the top of XAML files 
    3.Remember to use the namespace prefix (in the above example, <xctk: ...> or <xcdg: ...>) in the body of your XAML
```

Comment: I followed "Installation using NuGet". All I did was ran the command "Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" in the console and it fixed the 'The name "DataGrid" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WpfToolkit"'

Answer (score 2):

I have Found the same Error. You have to **uninstall** current install toolkit and **reinstall toolkit** it will solve the error.Its not a proper solution but you are able to continue you work.

Comment: Worked for me. Did install / uninstall via package manager for project.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Consider the [Extended WPF Toolkit - Numeric Up Down](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown), is obsolete. 
And they strongly suggest to use any of "specialized" versions. This, by the way, **shouldn't** generate an *Error*, but *Warning*.

What about not finding the assembly, check your project's and `Wpf Toolkit` versions compatibility.

Comment: I tried to use IntegerUpDown and I have same error. I have version 3.5.40128.1, from page http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535 (for .NET Framework 3.5)

Comment: and what is your project's version ?

Comment: But I haven't sp 1... Can be it reason?

Comment: I also... But I will try... So we haven't more ideas.