# WPFTookit.Extended - Fails to install

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, toolbox

I have followed the steps from several answers on StackOverflow to install the Extended WPF Toolkit Binaries. After downloading, I have attempted to add them to the Toolbox tab, adding a WPF Extend Tookit toolbox, and browsing to the location of the .dll. I answer Yes to the security question, and the progress bar does it's little dance and closes. Yet, I never have any controls show up. What am I missing?

Comment: Any reason you're not using NuGet for this?

Comment: *"I have followed the steps from several answers on StackOverflow to install the Extended WPF Toolkit Binaries."* Can you link to these answers in your question so we know which steps you're taking?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: I tried using NuGet several times, and no dice. That's why I tried the manual approach.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton: I found the solution on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298435/control-from-wpftoolkit-doesnt-exist-in-namespace link: The zip file has to be unblocked before it is unzipped. I don't know if overlooked that one step or not, but that solved my problem.

Comment: @KennZAney1 Glad to hear you have resolved your own question! Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of it so this question is properly marked as resolved. (I think new users may need to wait 24 hours first before they can accept their own answers.)

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Yes, the up-down icons are gray/grey now. I will check tomorrow. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (finally) found the key step to installing the WPFToolkit.Extended in a related post: [Control from WPFToolkit doesn't exist in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298435/control-from-wpftoolkit-doesnt-exist-in-namespace). This referred to the CodePlex site that had the crucial step: Unblock the .zip file:

(Step) 3. Unblock the ZIP file: Right-click ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip -> Properties -> Unblock